# How to add and remove a SKErmitterNode within a sequence?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sequences, sknode, particles

I'm adding a SKErmitterNode from the update() function. I want to remove the SKErmitterNode after 2 seconds, therefore I made a sequence but in the sequence, I can´t add Nodes. And if I add the Node outside of the sequence it gets added over and over again(because I´m doing all of this in the update function) Does someone know a better way to do this?

Here is my Code from the update function:

```
 override func update(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if player.position.y <= player.size.height / 2{

        self.player.removeFromParent()

        if let particles = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "MyParticle.sks") {
            particles.position = player.position

            let addParticle = addChild(particles)
            let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2.0)
            let removeParticle = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            let particleSequence = SKAction.sequence([addParticle, wait, removeParticle]) //Error ->Cannot convert value of type 'Void' to expected element type 'SKAction'
            self.run(SKAction.run(particleSequence))

        }
    }
```

Comment: What kind of effect are you trying to do? Like an explosion on the player?

Comment: Yes, an explosion. @sicvayne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I recommend for you to do is to create a function like the following

```
func myExplosion (explosionPosition: CGPoint){
    let explosion = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "MyParticle")// borrowed this from you
    explosion?.position = explosionPosition
    explosion?.zPosition = 3
    self.addChild(explosion!)
    self.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2)){//you can always change the duration to whatever you want
        explosion?.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

then when it is time to use this function, use it like so

```
myExplosion(explosionPosition: player.position)
```

Hope this can help you out.

Comment: It helps thanks, but because I have the code in the update function the SKErmitterNode gets added over and over again. How can I stop that? @sicvayne

Comment: You can mark it correct if it answered the question. As far as the update function, I recommend messing around with it see what you can find!